# Regenerating Public and Private Key based on modulus and public exponent

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I've only got started towards learning how RSA works and overall in cryptography and I've got a question. Lets say I only have the RSA modulus and the Public exponent of a Public Key:

```
n = AA18ABA43B50DEEF38598FAF87D2AB634E4571C130A9BCA7B878267414FAAB8B471BD8965F5C9FC3818485EAF529C26246F3055064A8DE19C8C338BE5496CBAEB059DC0B358143B44A35449EB264113121A455BD7FDE3FAC919E94B56FB9BB4F651CDB23EAD439D6CD523EB08191E75B35FD13A7419B3090F24787BD4F4E1967
e = 65537
```

And am trying to follow this guide to generate the public and private key: https://warrenguy.me/blog/regenerating-rsa-private-key-python

My question is, how can I literally get both the `private key` and the `public key`? For if you convert the `n` to its integer form, you get:

```
119445732379544598056145200053932732877863846799652384989588303737527328743970559883211146487286317168142202446955508902936035124709397221178664495721428029984726868375359168203283442617134197706515425366188396513684446494070223079865755643116690165578452542158755074958452695530623055205290232290667934914919
```

And that doesn't match the integer-digit size as specified in the guide.

EDIT:

OR, Is there any way to generate a signature for a file? given only the `n` and `e`? Which is of my primary objective, though I concluded that I might need the private and public keys along the line leading to me asking the main question.

Thank you very much,

Yato

Answer (score 2):

In RSA the public key is `(n, e)`, which you already have. Deriving the private key from the modulus is the exact thing RSA wants to be difficult. This is known as the [factoring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoring_problem). If this was a tractable problem computationally then RSA would not be a useful cryptosystem. In fact, as computers have gotten faster and algorithms for factoring have improved (see: [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve)) the recommended bit length of an RSA key has gotten longer to combat this. Where 1024 was once considered acceptable today 2048 is a minimum recommendation.

You can't sign without the private key, as the idea is that a signature demonstrates possession of the private key and you use the public key (which you distribute in some fashion to the parties who need to validate the signature) to confirm that the signature is genuine. Frequently this is combined with X.509 to provide some identity binding, but it isn't required.